# Adaptive Server connection failed with Laravel 5.2 after PHP update

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

I'm working on a system with Laravel 5.2 and I connect it to SQL Server with no problems, until I upgraded from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6, and now when I try to login it's throwing me the next exception:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

When I run `php artisan migrate` on console, it runs with no errors and do the migration correctly. The same when I run `php artisan db:seed`. The problem, I think, is when I try to connect to sql server with PHP.

Is there another configuration I have to do, or library I have to update or install? I think it may be pdolib, but I haven't found information that can help me.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

I executed `tsql -C` and noticed there was another freetds.conf in

> /usr/local/php5/etc

Then, I edited it with the information on my freetds located in

> /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.24/etc/freetds.conf

and now I can login and make queries as before.

Hope it helps to some one.